# SonarQube Installation Issue - “Fail to unzip plugin [python]”…”Operation not permitted”

Tags: permissions, kubernetes, nfs, installation, sonarqube

I'm having an issue where SonarQube 10.1.0 Community seems to be having a difficult starting for the first time.

I've set it up using Kubernetes (K3s v1.27.1) and adapted the official SonarQube Helm chart to be able to use it with my own infrastructure and have more control.

## Logs

```
2023.07.02 21:55:21 INFO  es[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded module [aggregations]
2023.07.02 21:55:21 INFO  es[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded module [analysis-common]
2023.07.02 21:55:21 INFO  es[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded module [apm]
2023.07.02 21:55:21 INFO  es[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded module [blob-cache]
2023.07.02 21:55:21 INFO  es[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded module [lang-painless]
2023.07.02 21:55:21 INFO  es[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded module [old-lucene-versions]
2023.07.02 21:55:21 INFO  es[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded module [parent-join]
2023.07.02 21:55:21 INFO  es[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded module [reindex]
2023.07.02 21:55:21 INFO  es[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded module [transport-netty4]
2023.07.02 21:55:21 INFO  es[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded module [x-pack-aggregate-metric]
2023.07.02 21:55:21 INFO  es[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded module [x-pack-core]
2023.07.02 21:55:21 INFO  es[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded module [x-pack-profiling]
2023.07.02 21:55:21 INFO  es[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded module [x-pack-security]
2023.07.02 21:55:21 INFO  es[][o.e.p.PluginsService] no plugins loaded
2023.07.02 21:55:24 INFO  es[][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment] using [1] data paths, mounts [[/opt/sonarqube/data (10.0.1.1:/mnt/ZPool1/Kubernetes/cluster0/personal-19/sonarqube/data)]], net usable_space [4.7tb], net total_space [4.7tb], types [nfs4]
2023.07.02 21:55:24 INFO  es[][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment] heap size [512mb], compressed ordinary object pointers [true]
2023.07.02 21:55:24 INFO  es[][o.e.n.Node] node name [sonarqube], node ID [lKa0DhO4Ss2jrx089YgiuA], cluster name [sonarqube], roles [ml, data_hot, transform, data_content, data_warm, master, remote_cluster_client, data, data_cold, ingest, data_frozen]
2023.07.02 21:55:24 INFO  es[][o.e.x.p.ProfilingPlugin] Profiling is enabled
2023.07.02 21:55:24 INFO  es[][o.e.x.s.Security] Security is disabled
2023.07.02 21:55:24 INFO  es[][o.e.t.n.NettyAllocator] creating NettyAllocator with the following configs: [name=unpooled, suggested_max_allocation_size=1mb, factors={es.unsafe.use_unpooled_allocator=null, g1gc_enabled=true, g1gc_region_size=4mb, heap_size=512mb}]
2023.07.02 21:55:24 INFO  es[][o.e.i.r.RecoverySettings] using rate limit [40mb] with [default=40mb, read=0b, write=0b, max=0b]
2023.07.02 21:55:24 INFO  es[][o.e.d.DiscoveryModule] using discovery type [single-node] and seed hosts providers [settings]
2023.07.02 21:55:25 INFO  es[][o.e.n.Node] initialized
2023.07.02 21:55:25 INFO  es[][o.e.n.Node] starting ...
2023.07.02 21:55:25 INFO  es[][o.e.t.TransportService] publish_address {127.0.0.1:35691}, bound_addresses {127.0.0.1:35691}
2023.07.02 21:55:25 INFO  es[][o.e.b.BootstrapChecks] explicitly enforcing bootstrap checks
2023.07.02 21:55:25 WARN  es[][o.e.c.c.ClusterBootstrapService] this node is locked into cluster UUID [HDZkyFIkRi2sp_BveAdgVg] but [cluster.initial_master_nodes] is set to [sonarqube]; remove this setting to avoid possible data loss caused by subsequent cluster bootstrap attempts; for further information see https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.7/important-settings.html#initial_master_nodes
2023.07.02 21:55:25 INFO  es[][o.e.c.s.MasterService] elected-as-master ([1] nodes joined)[_FINISH_ELECTION_, {sonarqube}{lKa0DhO4Ss2jrx089YgiuA}{nLZiwfHqTwyq1R1mRHYZJA}{sonarqube}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:35691}{cdfhilmrstw}{8.7.0} completing election], term: 4, version: 14, delta: master node changed {previous [], current [{sonarqube}{lKa0DhO4Ss2jrx089YgiuA}{nLZiwfHqTwyq1R1mRHYZJA}{sonarqube}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:35691}{cdfhilmrstw}{8.7.0}]}
2023.07.02 21:55:26 INFO  es[][o.e.c.s.ClusterApplierService] master node changed {previous [], current [{sonarqube}{lKa0DhO4Ss2jrx089YgiuA}{nLZiwfHqTwyq1R1mRHYZJA}{sonarqube}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:35691}{cdfhilmrstw}{8.7.0}]}, term: 4, version: 14, reason: Publication{term=4, version=14}
2023.07.02 21:55:26 INFO  es[][o.e.r.s.FileSettingsService] starting file settings watcher ...
2023.07.02 21:55:26 INFO  es[][o.e.r.s.FileSettingsService] file settings service up and running [tid=30]
2023.07.02 21:55:26 INFO  es[][o.e.h.AbstractHttpServerTransport] publish_address {127.0.0.1:9001}, bound_addresses {127.0.0.1:9001}
2023.07.02 21:55:26 INFO  es[][o.e.c.c.NodeJoinExecutor] node-join: [{sonarqube}{lKa0DhO4Ss2jrx089YgiuA}{nLZiwfHqTwyq1R1mRHYZJA}{sonarqube}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:35691}{cdfhilmrstw}{8.7.0}] with reason [completing election]
2023.07.02 21:55:26 INFO  es[][o.e.n.Node] started {sonarqube}{lKa0DhO4Ss2jrx089YgiuA}{nLZiwfHqTwyq1R1mRHYZJA}{sonarqube}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:35691}{cdfhilmrstw}{8.7.0}{xpack.installed=true, rack_id=sonarqube}
2023.07.02 21:55:26 INFO  es[][o.e.l.LicenseService] license [bdd74327-7981-4b82-af56-5b0a01c50f5a] mode [basic] - valid
2023.07.02 21:55:26 INFO  es[][o.e.g.GatewayService] recovered [0] indices into cluster_state
2023.07.02 21:55:26 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process[es] is up
2023.07.02 21:55:26 INFO  app[][o.s.a.ProcessLauncherImpl] Launch process[WEB_SERVER] from [/opt/sonarqube]: /opt/java/openjdk/bin/java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/sonarqube/temp -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=java.base/jdk.internal.ref=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.nio=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.management/sun.management=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=jdk.management/com.sun.management.internal=ALL-UNNAMED -Dcom.redhat.fips=false -Xmx512m -Xms128m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=localhost|127.*|[::1] -cp ./lib/sonar-application-10.1.0.73491.jar:/opt/sonarqube/lib/jdbc/postgresql/postgresql-42.6.0.jar org.sonar.server.app.WebServer /opt/sonarqube/temp/sq-process9317971875660968072properties
2023.07.02 21:55:26 INFO  es[][o.e.h.n.s.HealthNodeTaskExecutor] Node [{sonarqube}{lKa0DhO4Ss2jrx089YgiuA}] is selected as the current health node.
WARNING: A terminally deprecated method in java.lang.System has been called
WARNING: System::setSecurityManager has been called by org.sonar.process.PluginSecurityManager (file:/opt/sonarqube/lib/sonar-application-10.1.0.73491.jar)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.sonar.process.PluginSecurityManager
WARNING: System::setSecurityManager will be removed in a future release
2023.07.02 21:55:26 INFO  web[][o.s.p.ProcessEntryPoint] Starting Web Server
2023.07.02 21:55:27 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.LogServerVersion] SonarQube Server / 10.1.0.73491 / 53c01c35c264c7e3d76cf5fb955de406f36b115e
2023.07.02 21:55:27 INFO  web[][o.s.d.DefaultDatabase] Create JDBC data source for jdbc:postgresql://postgresql-service:5432/sonarqube
2023.07.02 21:55:27 INFO  web[][c.z.h.HikariDataSource] HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2023.07.02 21:55:27 INFO  web[][c.z.h.p.HikariPool] HikariPool-1 - Added connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@73a00e09
2023.07.02 21:55:27 INFO  web[][c.z.h.HikariDataSource] HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2023.07.02 21:55:28 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.ServerFileSystemImpl] SonarQube home: /opt/sonarqube
2023.07.02 21:55:28 INFO  web[][o.s.s.u.SystemPasscodeImpl] System authentication by passcode is disabled
2023.07.02 21:55:29 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.ServerPluginManager] Deploy C# Code Quality and Security / 9.3.0.71466 / e47cf88a6286a446a098754e5775535a330f58d7

<<Omitted lines for character limit>>

2023.07.02 21:55:29 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.ServerPluginManager] Deploy XML Code Quality and Security / 2.8.1.4006 / 80e5629b173cd7a47c04e97cbe1a263db84ff844
2023.07.02 21:55:29 WARN  web[][o.s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext] Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@61a88b8c-org.sonar.server.plugins.ServerPluginManager': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fail to unzip plugin [python] /opt/sonarqube/lib/extensions/sonar-python-plugin-4.3.0.11660.jar to /opt/sonarqube/data/web/deploy/plugins/python
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@61a88b8c-org.sonar.server.plugins.ServerPluginManager': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fail to unzip plugin [python] /opt/sonarqube/lib/extensions/sonar-python-plugin-4.3.0.11660.jar to /opt/sonarqube/data/web/deploy/plugins/python
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:628)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:955)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:920)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.SpringComponentContainer.startComponents(SpringComponentContainer.java:187)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.platformlevel.PlatformLevel.start(PlatformLevel.java:80)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.platformlevel.PlatformLevel2.start(PlatformLevel2.java:101)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.PlatformImpl.start(PlatformImpl.java:214)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.PlatformImpl.startLevel2Container(PlatformImpl.java:186)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.PlatformImpl.init(PlatformImpl.java:80)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.web.PlatformServletContextListener.contextInitialized(PlatformServletContextListener.java:45)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4494)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4946)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1332)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1322)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:871)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:795)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1332)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1322)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:871)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:249)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:428)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:917)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.sonar.server.app.EmbeddedTomcat.start(EmbeddedTomcat.java:71)
    at org.sonar.server.app.WebServer.start(WebServer.java:55)
    at org.sonar.process.ProcessEntryPoint.launch(ProcessEntryPoint.java:97)
    at org.sonar.process.ProcessEntryPoint.launch(ProcessEntryPoint.java:81)
    at org.sonar.server.app.WebServer.main(WebServer.java:104)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fail to unzip plugin [python] /opt/sonarqube/lib/extensions/sonar-python-plugin-4.3.0.11660.jar to /opt/sonarqube/data/web/deploy/plugins/python
    at org.sonar.server.plugins.ServerPluginJarExploder.explode(ServerPluginJarExploder.java:60)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap$ValueSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluateToArrayNode(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.toArray(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.toArray(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.toList(Unknown Source)
    at org.sonar.server.plugins.ServerPluginManager.extractPlugins(ServerPluginManager.java:86)
    at org.sonar.server.plugins.ServerPluginManager.start(ServerPluginManager.java:65)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.StartableBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(StartableBeanPostProcessor.java:33)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:440)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1796)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620)
    ... 44 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.nio.file.FileSystemException: /opt/sonarqube/data/web/deploy/plugins/python/sonar-python-plugin-4.3.0.11660.jar: Operation not permitted
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixCopyFile.copyFile(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixCopyFile.copy(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.copy(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.copy(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyFile(FileUtils.java:850)
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyFile(FileUtils.java:756)
    at org.sonar.server.plugins.ServerPluginJarExploder.explode(ServerPluginJarExploder.java:56)
    ... 59 common frames omitted
2023.07.02 21:55:29 INFO  web[][c.z.h.HikariDataSource] HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2023.07.02 21:55:29 INFO  web[][c.z.h.HikariDataSource] HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
2023.07.02 21:55:29 INFO  web[][o.s.s.a.EmbeddedTomcat] HTTP connector enabled on port 9000
2023.07.02 21:55:29 INFO  web[][o.s.p.ProcessEntryPoint] Hard stopping process
2023.07.02 21:55:29 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process[Web Server] is stopped
2023.07.02 21:55:29 WARN  app[][o.s.a.p.AbstractManagedProcess] Process exited with exit value [ElasticSearch]: 143
2023.07.02 21:55:29 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process[ElasticSearch] is stopped
2023.07.02 21:55:29 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] SonarQube is stopped
```

I’m unable to find much information online about this or even really know what exactly to search for at the moment. It seems like it’s a file system permissions issue, however, I cannot find issues, going so far as to setting all initial container files at `/opt/sonarqube/*` to `777` with `owner` and `group` being `sonarqube`.

## Adjacent?

I use NFS as my storage backend through K8s Persistent Volume Claims, and suspect that it maybe be related to the issues, but cannot determine why.

I see on the [Install the Server](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/setup-and-upgrade/install-the-server/#installing-sonarqube-from-the-docker-image) page:
[image: Warning notice saying "Make sure you're using volumes as shown with the above commands, and not bind mounts. Using bind mounts prevents plugins from populating correctly.]

This warning for storage-related setups makes me suspicious it has something to do with my storage setup, but again, cannot figure out why, or even why bind mounts using Docker directly would have issues. Also similar is [Deploy SonarQube on Kubernetes](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/setup-and-upgrade/deploy-on-kubernetes/deploy-sonarqube-on-kubernetes/#known-limitations) mentioning known issues on Azure Kubernetes Service with the Fileshare PVC.

## Debugging Attempts

Going through the logs:

Looking at: `nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fail to unzip plugin [python] /opt/sonarqube/lib/extensions/sonar-python-plugin-4.3.0.11660.jar to /opt/sonarqube/data/web/deploy/plugins/python`

I can go to `/opt/sonarqube/lib/extensions/` and see:

```
sonarqube@sonarqube-deployment-cff8497f8-5mbrb:/opt/sonarqube$ ls -AGhl lib/extensions
total 144M
-r-xr-xr-x 1 root 9.0M Jun 20 13:44 sonar-cayc-plugin-2.0.0.334.jar
-r-xr-xr-x 1 root  28K Jun 20 13:44 sonar-config-plugin-1.2.0.267.jar
-r-xr-xr-x 1 root 4.9M Jun 20 13:44 sonar-csharp-plugin-9.3.0.71466.jar
-r-xr-xr-x 1 root 1.2M Jun 20 13:44 sonar-flex-plugin-2.9.0.3375.jar
-r-xr-xr-x 1 root 7.7M Jun 20 13:44 sonar-go-plugin-1.13.0.4374.jar
-r-xr-xr-x 1 root 528K Jun 20 13:44 sonar-html-plugin-3.8.0.3510.jar
-r-xr-xr-x 1 root 1.5M Jun 20 13:44 sonar-iac-plugin-1.17.0.3976.jar
-r-xr-xr-x 1 root  23K Jun 20 13:44 sonar-jacoco-plugin-1.3.0.1538.jar
-r-xr-xr-x 1 root  18M Jun 20 13:44 sonar-java-plugin-7.20.0.31692.jar
-r-xr-xr-x 1 root  20M Jun 20 13:44 sonar-javascript-plugin-10.3.1.21905.jar
-r-xr-xr-x 1 root  36M Jun 20 13:44 sonar-kotlin-plugin-2.15.0.2579.jar
-r-xr-xr-x 1 root 5.5M Jun 20 13:44 sonar-php-plugin-3.30.0.9766.jar
-r-xr-xr-x 1 root 8.0M Jun 20 13:44 sonar-python-plugin-4.3.0.11660.jar
-r-xr-xr-x 1 root  14M Jun 20 13:44 sonar-ruby-plugin-1.13.0.4374.jar
-r-xr-xr-x 1 root  13M Jun 20 13:44 sonar-scala-plugin-1.13.0.4374.jar
-r-xr-xr-x 1 root 112K Jun 20 13:44 sonar-text-plugin-2.1.0.1163.jar
-r-xr-xr-x 1 root 4.3M Jun 20 13:44 sonar-vbnet-plugin-9.3.0.71466.jar
-r-xr-xr-x 1 root 2.4M Jun 20 13:44 sonar-xml-plugin-2.8.1.4006.jar
```

All files are readable to the `sonarqube` user.

I can go to `/opt/sonarqube/data/web/deploy/plugins/` and see:

```
sonarqube@sonarqube-deployment-cff8497f8-5mbrb:/opt/sonarqube$ stat /opt/sonarqube/data/web/deploy/plugins/python/
  File: /opt/sonarqube/data/web/deploy/plugins/python/
  Size: 2               Blocks: 1          IO Block: 1048576 directory
Device: 31h/49d Inode: 65074       Links: 2
Access: (0777/drwxrwxrwx)  Uid: ( 1000/sonarqube)   Gid: ( 1000/sonarqube)
Access: 2023-07-02 21:55:59.219114423 +0000
Modify: 2023-07-02 21:55:59.395114311 +0000
Change: 2023-07-02 22:35:24.553474386 +0000
 Birth: -
```

And so the directory is writeable to all users.

I believe the java application should be running under the `sonarqube` user, so I don’t see why there would be an issue there.

## Kubernetes Declarations

### Deployment (I'll use StatefulSet eventually...)

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: sonarqube-deployment
  namespace: personal-19
  labels:
    app: sonarqube

spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: sonarqube
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: sonarqube
        app-group: sonarqube
    spec:
      affinity:
        podAffinity:
          preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
          - weight: 100
            podAffinityTerm:
              topologyKey: "kubernetes.io/hostname"
              labelSelector:
                matchExpressions:
                - key: app-group
                  operator: In
                  values:
                  - sonarqube
      initContainers:
      - name: set-sysctl-options
        image: docker.io/busybox:1.32
        command: [ "/bin/sh", "-c" ]
        args:
        - |
          if [[ "$(sysctl -n vm.max_map_count)" -lt 524288 ]]; then
            sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=524288
          fi
          if [[ "$(sysctl -n fs.file-max)" -lt 131072 ]]; then
            sysctl -w fs.file-max=131072
          fi
          if [[ "$(ulimit -n)" != "unlimited" ]]; then
            if [[ "$(ulimit -n)" -lt 131072 ]]; then
              echo "ulimit -n 131072"
              ulimit -n 131072
            fi
          fi
          if [[ "$(ulimit -u)" != "unlimited" ]]; then
            if [[ "$(ulimit -u)" -lt 8192 ]]; then
              echo "ulimit -u 8192"
              ulimit -u 8192
            fi
          fi
        securityContext:
          privileged: true
          # runAsUser: 1000
          # runAsGroup: 1000
          # readOnlyRootFilesystem: false
      - name: reset-filesystem-permissions
        image: docker.io/ubuntu:23.04
        command: [ "/bin/sh", "-c" ]
        args:
        - |
          chown -R 1000:1000 /opt/sonarqube
          chmod -R 777 /opt/sonarqube
        volumeMounts:
        - name: sonarqube-volume-data
          mountPath: /opt/sonarqube/data/
        - name: sonarqube-volume-extensions
          mountPath: /opt/sonarqube/extensions/
        - name: sonarqube-volume-logs
          mountPath: /opt/sonarqube/logs/
      containers:
      - name: sonarqube
        image: docker.io/sonarqube:10.1.0-community
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        # command: [ "sleep", "infinity" ]
        # securityContext:
          # privileged: true
          # runAsUser: 1000
          # runAsGroup: 1000
          # readOnlyRootFilesystem: false
        env:
        - name: SONAR_JDBC_URL
          value: 'jdbc:postgresql://postgresql-service:5432/sonarqube'
        - name: SONAR_JDBC_USERNAME
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: personal-19-secrets
              key: Database-User
        - name: SONAR_JDBC_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: personal-19-secrets
              key: Database-Password
        ports:
        - protocol: TCP
          containerPort: 9000
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 500m
            memory: 2Gi
          limits:
            cpu: 4000m
            memory: 8Gi
        volumeMounts:
        - name: sonarqube-volume-data
          mountPath: /opt/sonarqube/data/
        - name: sonarqube-volume-extensions
          mountPath: /opt/sonarqube/extensions/
        - name: sonarqube-volume-logs
          mountPath: /opt/sonarqube/logs/
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 3600
      volumes:
      - name: sonarqube-volume-data
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: sonarqube-volumeclaim-data
      - name: sonarqube-volume-extensions
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: sonarqube-volumeclaim-extensions
      - name: sonarqube-volume-logs
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: sonarqube-volumeclaim-logs
```

### Storage

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: personal-19-sonarqube-persistentvolume-data

spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteMany
  capacity:
    storage: 10Gi
  storageClassName: personal-19-sonarqube-storageclass-data
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  nfs:
    server: 10.0.1.1
    path: /mnt/ZPool1/Kubernetes/cluster0/personal-19/sonarqube/data/
  mountOptions:
  - nfsvers=4.2
  - hard # `soft` may cause silent data corruption; `hard` requires requests to be retried indefinitely and is "not allowed to fail"
  - async # `async` can always be used, as application can command when data is flushed to disk (Basic write-caching)
  - proto=tcp
  - timeo=10 # read & write request timeout (in tenths of a second)
  - rsize=1048576 # the maximum number of bytes the client is allowed to request in a single read request
  - wsize=1048576 # the maximum number of bytes the client is allowed to request in a single write request
  - ac # enable file attribute caching
  - noatime # do not need to update file access times
  - nodiratime # do not need to update directory access times

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: personal-19-sonarqube-persistentvolume-extensions

spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteMany
  capacity:
    storage: 10Gi
  storageClassName: personal-19-sonarqube-storageclass-extensions
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  nfs:
    server: 10.0.1.1
    path: /mnt/ZPool1/Kubernetes/cluster0/personal-19/sonarqube/extensions/
  mountOptions:
  - nfsvers=4.2
  - hard # `soft` may cause silent data corruption; `hard` requires requests to be retried indefinitely and is "not allowed to fail"
  - async # `async` can always be used, as application can command when data is flushed to disk (Basic write-caching)
  - proto=tcp
  - timeo=10 # read & write request timeout (in tenths of a second)
  - rsize=1048576 # the maximum number of bytes the client is allowed to request in a single read request
  - wsize=1048576 # the maximum number of bytes the client is allowed to request in a single write request
  - ac # enable file attribute caching
  - noatime # do not need to update file access times
  - nodiratime # do not need to update directory access times

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: personal-19-sonarqube-persistentvolume-logs

spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteMany
  capacity:
    storage: 10Gi
  storageClassName: personal-19-sonarqube-storageclass-logs
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  nfs:
    server: 10.0.1.1
    path: /mnt/ZPool1/Kubernetes/cluster0/personal-19/sonarqube/logs/
  mountOptions:
  - nfsvers=4.2
  - hard # `soft` may cause silent data corruption; `hard` requires requests to be retried indefinitely and is "not allowed to fail"
  - async # `async` can always be used, as application can command when data is flushed to disk (Basic write-caching)
  - proto=tcp
  - timeo=10 # read & write request timeout (in tenths of a second)
  - rsize=1048576 # the maximum number of bytes the client is allowed to request in a single read request
  - wsize=1048576 # the maximum number of bytes the client is allowed to request in a single write request
  - ac # enable file attribute caching
  - noatime # do not need to update file access times
  - nodiratime # do not need to update directory access times

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: sonarqube-volumeclaim-data
  namespace: personal-19

spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 10Gi
  storageClassName: personal-19-sonarqube-storageclass-data
  volumeMode: Filesystem

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: sonarqube-volumeclaim-extensions
  namespace: personal-19

spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 10Gi
  storageClassName: personal-19-sonarqube-storageclass-extensions
  volumeMode: Filesystem

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: sonarqube-volumeclaim-logs
  namespace: personal-19

spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 10Gi
  storageClassName: personal-19-sonarqube-storageclass-logs
  volumeMode: Filesystem
```

## Ideas?

If anyone has any ideas on things I can look into, I would greatly appreciate any input! Thank you!